# MySQL unstable switches between available and "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'" in matter of seconds

Tags: linux, mysql, nas, synology

Using libmysql - 5.1.49 on a Synology NAS (v4.2)

MySQL is very unstable, it switches from being available where I can login trough phpMyAdmin to unreachable where I get the error message "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'" (clients cannot connect as well).

Comment: What's showing up in the MySQL error log?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/VtvGTNFF

Comment: Your InnoDB table files appear to be broken. Have you followed the suggestions given in the log for what to do about that? (As a general note, the frequency, alacrity, and usefulness of responses you receive on Super User, and on Stack Overflow sites in general, scales proportionally to the degree of effort you put into solving the problem before you ask your questions -- which is a long-winded way of saying you'd have done well to look at the log output and try what it suggests, before asking a question here.)